# Why t[1] output is 1 for local t = {1, [1] = "a", [2] = "b"}

Tags: lua

Test Code:

```
local t = {1, [1] = "a", [2] = "b"}
print("t[1]: ", t[1])
for _, v in pairs(t) do
    print(v)
end
```

Output:

```
t[1]: 1
1
b
```

Comment: Table constructor must not have duplicated keys.  You've defined key `[1]` twice: as keyless item `1` and as key-value pair `[1]="a"`.

Comment: why is the 1, i can't find "a",  What is the order of table construction?

Comment: because `local t = {1, [1] = "a", [2] = "b"}` is the same as `local t = {[1] = 1, [1] = "a", [2] = "b"}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order that fields are set in table constructors is not defined if you have duplicate keys.

Currently, the compiler batches list entries (50 list entries per batch).

The bytecode for your constructor can be seen by running `luac -l` on your script:

```
1   [1] NEWTABLE    0 1 2
2   [1] LOADK       1 -1    ; 1
3   [1] SETTABLE    0 -1 -2 ; 1 "a"
4   [1] SETTABLE    0 -3 -4 ; 2 "b"
5   [1] SETLIST     0 1 1   ; 1
```

Note the SETLIST at the end. For `{10,20,30, [1] = "a", [2] = "b"}`, the bytecode is:

```
1   [1] NEWTABLE    0 3 2
2   [1] LOADK       1 -1    ; 10
3   [1] LOADK       2 -2    ; 20
4   [1] LOADK       3 -3    ; 30
5   [1] SETTABLE    0 -4 -5 ; 1 "a"
6   [1] SETTABLE    0 -6 -7 ; 2 "b"
7   [1] SETLIST     0 3 1   ; 1
```

If the constructor began with a list of length 60 say, then the final value of t[1] would be "a".

Comment: Ref:["The order of the assignments in a constructor is undefined.  (This order would be relevant only when there are repeated keys.)"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) (Your manual is part of what makes Lua great.)